# OSGI Embedded Equinox - Bundle to access pojos not instantiated in osgi framework

Tags: osgi, equinox

I have a server side application and want to embed an osgi framework into for dynamic bundle loading.
Suppose I want to expose a QuoteImpl implementing IQuote(instantiated as part of the server container bootstrap/Spring) to be used by different Bundles.

Q1. Is there a clean way of exposing server-application instances to Bundles ? (btw because of legacy it is not possible to make server code into bundle :) and donot want to make entire application osgi'ed.

Tried exposing via a service and bundle to cast into an IQuote.  Not sure I am doing it well but fails with unresolved compilation problems as IQuote resides in the core app projects as opposed to the bundle project.  any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the way to do this is with a service. The "host" application would publish the service and the bundles inside OSGi would consume the service in the normal way.

The key to get this working is that the service API (i.e. the package containing `IQuote`) must be exported by the host application through the system bundle exports. You can control this by setting the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property when you create the embedded OSGi framework. I wrote a [blog post](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html) on this subject that should help you get started (look for the heading "Exposing Application Packages").

You state that you have compilation problems. To fix those it's necessary to know how you have structured your projects and build system.

Comment: Neil Thanks a lot for coming back.  I used your blog indeed for guidelines.

Comment: Great blog btw.  I solved the compilation issue.  I have 3 projects Quote bundle(containing interface IQuote), Consumer bundle(using the IQuote) and Launcher project(mimics my app server (not a bundle)and programmatically register an implemntation of servic IQuote).  I get a NULL for serviceReference in the consumer bundle when I try to do context.getServiceReference(IQuoteService.class.getName()); 
My question is : Surely i missing something. Does implementation HAS to be in a bundle? Launcher registers the Service when i start the framework (not in Activator)

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args){  
 ..  
 FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();  config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,"osgi.main");  
Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);  
framework.start();  
    
 BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();  
 context.registerService(IQuoteService.class.getName(), new SimpleQuote(),null);
 ..
}`

Comment: APOLOGIES I cannot get teh comment lto linebreak :)..<br/>  Also from your blog, quote " The bundle that uses this package should have the following in its manifest: Import-Package: org.example.mydomain.".  
This causes a error in bundle Manifest saying "No bundle exports package org.example.mydomain".

Comment: Regarding the error message that says "no bundle exports this package", is that a build-time error? If so, then again I need to know about your build system. It sounds like the tool you are using is very inflexible and is getting in your way more than it is helping!

Comment: Regarding the NULL you get for service reference... this is what I would expect if you have not been able to put the `Import-Package: org.example.mydomain` into the consumer bundle. You really do need this import statement, so you need to find a way to get your tool to accept it (or use a better tool!).

Comment: Thanks Neil.Error is at IDE compiletime (in eclipse helios RCP).Have 3 projects(Launcher(java),Consumer(plugin project),IQuote(plugin project).  I want export the Consumer into a consumer.jar which i load in launcher. The implementation of IQuote is in launcher project in pkg org.launch.quoteimpl. I then try to put the `Import-Package:org.launch.quoteimpl` in the MANIFEST of Consumer.  Eclipse IDE complains that no bundle export org.launch.serviceimpl.

Comment: @Slash Ah, using Eclipse PDE for OSGi development is quite painful. In this case the error is very stupid... how can PDE know that there will not be a bundle at runtime that exports the package?? Unfortunately you might have to work around it by creating a dummy bundle project that exports the package; but be careful not to deploy this dummy project to the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I embedded Equinox OSGi runtime in my Java class. I suppose you could do the same. https://github.com/sarxos/equinox-launcher/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/sarxos/equinox/Launcher.java